# Slow boot when using kernel parameter console=ttyS0 to hide all output

Tags: kernel, boot, performance, console, serial-console

For an end-user friendly operating system, I am creating a basic linux distribution using the Buildroot tool. I am using Syslinux/Isolinux as the bootloader and the Linux 4.14.54 (Long Term Support) kernel. If I boot the ISO file via Virtualbox everything is working as expected. But when I burn that ISO onto an USB stick, the bootloader loads the initrd and the linux boot at some point seems to be freezed or slowed down. **After 30 seconds**, two small 'tux' images appear in the upper left corner (they normally never appear!) and the resolution changed to  the monitor's native resolution (1600x900). Afterwards the boot seems to continue properly and the x server starts.

The kernel parameters look like this: `vt.global_cursor_default=0 console=ttyS0`

As you can see, i specify `ttyS0` as console to hide all boot messages, by redirecting them to a non-existing serial console. I checked dmesg and did  not see any problematic messages (but the last message was from **16** seconds after boot). When I change the console parameter to `console=tty1` , it works flawlessly, the last dmesg message is from **4** seconds after boot, but there is much stuff written onto the console.

I tested this on my Lenovo S20-30 Touch Laptop.

The console parameter is the only option for me, since other options like setting the kernel log level has no effect on some messages (i.e. `printf` in a shell script). Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better alternative to hide **really all** console output?

Comment: Try `vt.color=0x00`.

Comment: You could try setting the baud rate, `console=ttyS0,115200` but I dont know what is happening if you dont have a ttyS0.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately `console=ttyS0,115200` did not work for me. However, the vt color hack `0x00` fixed my problem in the result. I will use this solution now.